# Problems working with Desfire EV1 tags and nfcpy

Tags: python, nfc

Trying to write an ndef record to a Desfire EV1 tag isn't working. I believe this is because the tag isn't formatted, however, when I try to do that (with tagtool.py) I get an error.

I'm using an Adafruit PN532 attached to a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ via mini-UART (S0 instead of AMA0 as I need Bluetooth for something else).

```
python tagtool.py --device tty:S0 format
No handlers could be found for logger "nfc.llcp.sec"
[nfc.clf] searching for reader on path tty:S0
[nfc.clf] using PN532v1.6 at /dev/ttyS0
** waiting for a tag **
[nfc.tag.tt4] no ndef capability file
[nfc.tag.tt4] format error: no ndef or not writeable
Sorry, I could not format this tag.

python tagtool.py --device tty:S0 -v
No handlers could be found for logger "nfc.llcp.sec"
[nfc.clf] searching for reader on path tty:S0
[nfc.clf] using PN532v1.6 at /dev/ttyS0
** waiting for a tag **
Type4ATag MIU=63 FWT=0.077329
[nfc.tag.tt4] no ndef capability file
Memory Dump:
[nfc.tag.tt4] no ndef capability file

Python 2.7.13 (default, Sep 26 2018, 18:42:22)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nfc
No handlers could be found for logger "nfc.llcp.sec"
>>> clf = nfc.ContactlessFrontend('tty:S0')
>>> tag = clf.connect(rdwr={'on-connect': lambda tag: False})
>>> print(tag)
Type4ATag MIU=63 FWT=0.077329
>>> print(tag.ndef)
None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tagtool.py` script can format any NFC Forum Type 1/2/3/4 Tag. Those tags are equipped with NDEF management information that is defined by the NFC Forum tag specifications. Mifare Desfire EV1 is a multi-application capable tag with application identifiers (AID) and associated files. For NDEF storage a specific AID must be present with a defined file structure. This is usually done with manufacturer tools.

Comment: sorry to bother you but I was wondering if you could tell me how to make a NTAG213 read only? And what the process might be of determining which might be a lock byte. For example if I had a NTAG215, how could I make that tag read only. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63656816/how-to-make-a-nfc-tag-read-only