# How to make a NFC Tag read only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nfc, access-control, lockbits

I have an `NTAG213` NFC sticker. I was wondering how I can make this sticker read only. If later I switch to a `NTAG215`, how could I make that tag read only. What is the process involved in actually making different types of stickers read only. When I say read only, I mean the NFC's records cannot ever be modified but devices can still read the records without authentication.

I had a read of https://answers.launchpad.net/nfcpy/+question/242606 and tried to implement it's solution

```
import nfc
from time import sleep
from nfc.clf import RemoteTarget
import ndef

clf = nfc.ContactlessFrontend('usb')

while True:
    target = clf.sense(RemoteTarget('106A'), RemoteTarget('106B'), RemoteTarget('212F'))
    if target is None:
        sleep(1)
        continue

    serial = target.sdd_res.hex()
    tag = nfc.tag.activate(clf, target)

    if not tag.ndef:
        print("No NDEF records found!")
        continue
    
    for record in tag.ndef.records:
        print("Found record: " + str(record))

    record = ndef.UriRecord("https://www.example.com")
    tag.ndef.records = [record]
    # Code is fine until it gets to these tag indexes
    tag[15] = tag[15] | 0x0F
    tag[10] = 0xFF
    tag[11] = 0xFF
```

I get the error:

```
  File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
    tag[15] = tag[15] | 0x0F
TypeError: 'NTAG213' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: All details are in the card's datasheet https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf  There are various ways of doing it with writing to the right memory location to change the lock bits, there are 2 ways to permanently make the memory read-only (one each for various areas of memory) or probably much better is to password protect write operations (as this can be reversed if you know the password)

Comment: `tag` is a class, not an array. You can't access a class by an array index. You HAVE to use the functions defined in this class (or API).

Answer (score 0):

Looking that the Python library it has a simple method to make readonly using lock bytes or via password.

https://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable-0.10/modules/tag.html#nfc.tag.tt2_nxp.NTAG21x

Just call the `protect` method on the `tag` object with or without password (without password uses the lock bytes and is permanent read-only).

So the library has got programmed in it the right memory addresses and bits to flip for various cards including all the NTAG21x cards.